# Linear mixed effects analysis in R: Compare estimates of different reference grids (estimate at one value of a continuous variable versus another)

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I'm performing a linear mixed effects analysis to find out how locMap (categorical) and frequency (continuous) influence voltage (continuous):

```
lmer.voltage <- lmer(voltage ~ locMap + frequency + (1 | heart), data = df) 


Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           5.926e+00  4.479e-01  2.965e+01  13.229 5.71e-14 ***
LV                    6.542e+00  2.036e-01  5.819e+03  32.130  < 2e-16 ***
RA                   -1.371e+00  1.694e-01  5.878e+03  -8.093 7.00e-16 ***
RV                    2.820e+00  1.902e-01  5.893e+03  14.821  < 2e-16 ***
frequency            -1.154e-02  2.704e-03  5.721e+03  -4.269 2.00e-05 ***
```

**Is it possible to compare the estimates for voltage at frequency 90 vs. 145?**
Using ref_grid() and emmeans() I calculate the estimates with standard error and confidence interval for the desired frequencies.

```
grid90.voltage <- ref_grid(lmer.voltage, at = list(frequency = 90))
emmeans(grid90.voltage, specs = ~ loc_map, type = "response")

 locMap      emmean  SE    df    lower.CL upper.CL
 LA          4.89   0.305  6.55  4.15     5.62
 LV          11.43  0.293  5.55  10.70    12.16
 RA          3.52   0.275  4.34  2.78     4.26
 RV          7.71   0.286  5.05  6.97     8.44

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

In a graph, the estimates + 95%CIs look like this:

[image]

I know, that frequency has a significant effect on voltage in my analysis. But additionally, I would love to find out if there is a difference between the estimate at 90 and 145 bpm frequency. Is that possible?

Comment: Can say more about how the difference you are asking about (between 90 and 145bpm) is different than what you have already presented when using emmeans and the graph? I see a number of estimates of the estimated means and 95% CIs for 90 vs 145bpm.

Comment: I would like to get a p-value for the difference between each pair (90 vs. 145)

Comment: I would suggest you look at the contrast function from the marginaleffects package, although you could likely also get similar info from emmeans if you worked hard enough. https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/contrasts.html

Comment: The P value you asked for is 2 x 10^-5, same for each pair. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do something like

```
emmeans(lmer.voltage, pairwise ~ frequency, 
        at = list(frequency = c(90, 145)))
```

Even then, because this is such a simple model, this is in a way too elaborate, because you already have a test of the `frequency` effect from the table of fixed effects: $t = -4.269$, which is exactly what you will get from the pairwise comparison.

Your model estimates exactly *one* frequency effect that applies at all locations, and exactly *one* set of location effects that applies at all frequencies.
Perhaps, given that you question the effects at different frequencies, you should consider a less simple model that includes, say, an interaction between these predictors, and/or polynomial effects of frequency.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, the result of this is t.ratio = 4.256 for each pair. Not t=-4.269 
How come?

I thought it would make a difference which frequencies you were comparing, because the greater the difference between the frequencies, the less their confidence intervals overlapped.

Comment: Ahh now I understand that an estimate at 90 bpm (e.g. lowest value of CI) corresponds exactly to another estimate at 90 bpm (lowest of CI as well), since the values are calculated from the model.

Comment: Yes, everything that emmeans does is based on the model. I suggest doing some residual analysis (plots of residuals vs. predicted, residuals vs. location, residuals vs. frequency) to get an idea of whether the model fits. Maybe a statistical consultant can help make sure you're doing this all right. Many Us offer some kind of consulting.